# Display full name in rails select form defined in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actionview

I am working on rails 5 app. The issue I am facing is I am defining a drop down to select the user from another table in blogs form.The associations are as below.

blog.rb

```
has_many :blogs

def set_full_name
 self.full_name = [first_name, last_name].join(' ')
end
```

user.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

The problem is in this select form instead of displaying just the first_name in the drop-down list, I was to show the full_name of the user which I have defined in the user model. How can I do that?

```
<%= form.collection_select :user_id, User.all, :id, :first_name, {prompt: "Select"}, autofocus:true, class: "form-control", id: "user" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `:first_name` for the text property. Use `:full_name`

`<%= form.collection_select :user_id, User.all, :id, :full_name, {prompt: "Select"}, autofocus:true, class: "form-control", id: "user" %>`